How to include a Python package (NON ROS) into a ROS package?
I am trying to figure out the following:
I have one ROS noetic package. Let's call it ros_package.
I have another package that is NOT ROS that I made which contains Python code. Let's call it python_package.
I want to be able to import the module from python_package into ros_package so I can use its functions inside of the ros_package.
What is the recommended way to do this? I cannot modify the python_package and create a ROS wrapper around it.
edit:
When I say I cannot modify the python package, I mean I cannot add/remove/edit files that currently exist in that package. The package is setup as a standard standalone python package with a setup.py file in it. I can't "catkinize" the package by adding a CMakeLists.txt and a package.xml, and converting the setup.py to use distutils. It needs to stay a Python only (i.e. non ROS package).
I believe you can use the export tag to include a github repo at a specific commit hash through a requirements.txt file inside of my ROS package to include a python only (non ROS) package. I wonder if there are better approaches to this or if this is mainly the "best practice" way of using external Python only custom code in a ROS package.
Ultimately, what I would like is to have this Python package be stored locally under my ROS workspace and be able to be found by my ROS package.

Please explain "I cannot modify the python_package and create a ROS wrapper around it." What are your underlying constraints? This pushes it a lot towards an XY problem. And what have you tried already?

Also what have you researched for others approaches to this that aren't appropriate for you?  And how is the python library packaged itself?

Hopefully the information I added is helpful. Let me know if it isn't sufficient.

If you have a pure python package that you want to be able to use from within a ROS package. The easiest way to do this is to install that python package into the python environment (PYTHON_PATH) before you setup your ROS workspace on top. This is how most python based rosdep keys work with system packages installed and on your path. You can just use them from any ros package on the system.
